# Выполнение альтернативной процедуры для двух объектов

Tags: delphi, процедуры

Есть два объекта: Button1, Image1. Хочу, чтобы нажимая на картинку, выполнялась та же процедура, что и при нажатии на кнопку. Как реализовать:?

```
procedure TProForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
MessageBox(handle,'Нажали на кнопку! Нажмите на картинку','БД',mb_ok);
end;

procedure TProForm.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;
```

Можно, конечно, просто копировать всё то, что есть в первой процедуре, а что если код огромный, что делать?

Answer (score 2):

Все очень просто

```
procedure TProForm.Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myBtn: TButton;
  myImg: TImage;
begin 
 if Sender is TButton then
   begin
      myBtn := (Sender as TButton);
     //код, если нажата кнопка
   end;
 if Sender is TImage then
   begin
      myImg := (Sender as TImage);
     //код, если нажата картинка
   end;
 //общий код
end;
```

А в редакторе Events можете указать на эту процедуру для обоих объектов.
Либо сделать динамически, например в методе OnFormCreate:

```
myButton.onClick := self.Click;
myImage.onClick := self.Click;
```

Если мне не изменяет память, то вот так, нету под рукой дельфей, чтобы проверить.

**UPD**

А еще можно ваш способ использовать так:

```
procedure TProForm.CommonClick;
begin
 //ваш длинный код
end;

procedure TProForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 self.CommonClick;
end;

procedure TProForm.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 self.CommonClick;
end;
```

Или же мой:

```
procedure TProForm.Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myBtn: TButton;
  myImg: TImage;

 procedure DoSomthing;
 begin
  //ваш длинный код
 end;

begin 
 if Sender is TButton then
   begin
     myBtn := (Sender as TButton);
     DoSomthing;
   end;
 if Sender is TImage then
   begin
     myImg := (Sender as TImage);
     DoSomthing;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Так вместо //bla bla мне нужно писать один и тот же код в двух случаях? или же после двух условий писать код процедуры? Не совсем понял логики этого метода.

Comment: У вас может что-то отличатся, в зависимости от объекта, а что-то быть совместным.
Это просто пример, вы можете вообще убрать эти условия, если у вас полностью идентичный код.

Answer (score 1):

На вкладке Events вашей картинки в OnClick поставьте ваш buttonclick

Comment: "TPersistens в помощь" - уточните, что вы имеете ввиду?